# Simple Grammar Fails to Parse

Tags: antlr

I have the following simple ANTLR grammar:

```
grammar Grammar;

grammarRules : grammarRule+ ;

grammarRule:
    lhs '->' WORD+
    ;

lhs: ID ;

WORD : LETTER+ ;

ID : LETTER (LETTER|'0'..'9')* ;

fragment
LETTER : [a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF_] ;

WS : [ \t] -> skip ;
```

When I try to parse the string "webpage -> google search", I get the error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'webpage' expecting ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar is broken. The definition of `WORD` matches `webpage`. That's what the lexer returns, so the parser complains about not seeing an `ID`.

If you try to parse `webpage1 -> google search` it ought to work because `webpage1` is not a `WORD`.

The grammar isn't LL(*). Given e.g. the input a -> b c d -> e f, the parser would need to look ahead to the second `->` in order to feed information back to the lexer, causing to recognize `d` as an `ID` and not a `WORD`. ANTLER doesn't do that. (You probably wouldn't want it to, as this could complicate and consequently slow down the lexer considerably.)

You can fix the problem by adding a statement terminator like newline or semicolon to your language.

Comment: Ok, so the larger point, it seems, is that the lexer runs as its own layer completely distinct from the parser step, so the lexer is saddled with the responsibility of figuring out what to do in cases of ambiguity. In that respect, I'm curious why adding a statement terminator resolve the ambiguity problem.

Comment: @DanielBigham You're right. That probably won't be enough. You'll have to do something like `lhs -> ID | WORD`. With that you probably won't need a line terminator because ANTLR parsers are LL(*). (You would if they were only LL(1).)

Comment: For other people that may find this later -- I was pulling my hair out with Antlr getting all sorts of strange behavior, and then I read something about refactoring my grammar so that the primary grammar is contained with a single rule, rather than being broken up into many rules with different symbols.  This apparently allows the left-recursion of the grammar to be dealt with better. Presto, it is working well now.